# How to treat missing data involving multiple entries

Tags: dataset, missing-data

I'm developing a model used to predict the probability of a client changing telephone companies based on their daily usage. My dataset has information from two weeks (14 days).

My datasets include in each row:

User ID, day (number from 1 to 14), a list of 15 more values.

The problem comes from the fact that some clients don't use their telephones everyday so for each client we have a random amount of rows (from 1 to 14) depending on the days they have used their telephones. Therefore we have some missing client-day data combinations.

Removing the missing values is not an option since the data set is small and it would affect the predictive methods.

What kind of treatement could I make for this missing day values for each client?

I've tried to make a new dataset in which we have only one entry per client, there is a new value that quantifies the amount of days of telephone usage and the rest of values are a mean of all the values found on each day of the original dataset. This decreases the size of the dataset and we would have the same problem than just removing the missing values.

I've thought about adding values for the missing days for each client (using interpolation methods) but that would twist the results since that would make the dataset as if every client used their phones everyday and that would affect the predictive model.

Comment: Why not create a proportion out of the number of days the phone is used to create a single predictor out of the 14?

Comment: @André.B do you mean something similar to this? "I've tried to make a new dataset in which we have only one entry per client, there is a new value that quantifies the amount of days of telephone usage and the rest of values are a mean (proportion) of all the values found on each day of the original dataset. This decreases the size of the dataset and we would have the same problem than just removing the missing values." If not, I don't understand what do you mean about creating a single predictor out of the 14.

Comment: I need to read more carefully. Could you please post an example of your dataset? It seems to be in a non-standard format which will complicate things.

Comment: How are you defining your outcome/response variable? Whether the client changed companies at the end of 14 days, or some other way?  The structure of your observations and the specification of your predictors should be based on what you are trying to model.